# ¿ Como puedo mostrar una contraseña de un txt type password?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Como puedo mostrar una contraseña de un txt type password cuando presionen el mouse izquierdo y cuando lo dejen de presionar volver a esconder la contraseña

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te dejo una segunda alternativa, ya que en la mayoría de los casos que se desea tener esta funcionalidad se agrega un check en el formulario.

```js
function handleClick(cb) {
  if(cb.checked)
     $('#password').attr("type","text");
  else
    $('#password').attr("type","password");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="password" type="password" value="clave">
<input type="checkbox" name="check_mostrar" onclick='handleClick(this);'>Mostrar contraseña<br>
```

Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar los eventos `mousedown` y `mouseup`; con el `mousedown` puedes transformalo a tipo text y cuando lo sueltes con el `mouseup` lo restauras a su tipo anterior:

```js
$('#password').on("mousedown",function(event) {
  $(this).attr("type","text");
});

$('#password').on("mouseup",function(event) {
  $('#password').attr("type","password");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="password" type="password" value="clave">
```